# Why is a resolution missing from Xorg session, but not in Wayland?

Tags: ubuntu, screen-resolution, xorg, wayland, xrandr

I run Ubuntu 22.10 on Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 2020. Its graphic card is Mesa Intel® Xe (TGL GT2). I noticed the following:

- When I log in to the Ubuntu desktop environment (which is default), I can choose the 1440x900 resolution (16x10 aspect ratio).
- When I log in to Ubuntu on Xorg desktop environment, the 1440x900 resolution is not offered as an option.

I see the same behaviour through both the GUI (Settings > Display), and command line (xrandr). Also, the above resolution was available on Xorg in Ubuntu 22.04.

Why is this happenning? How can I re-enable 1440x900 resolution for the Xorg environment again?

Comment: This should either be on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange or on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm afraid I've already asked on both, and sadly haven't received an answer.